# Importing a module with imp

Tags: python, import

I have a script that does the following:

```
import imp
imp.load_source("storage_configuration_reader","/bi/opt/RNAspace/rnaspace_sources/rnaspace/rnaspace/rnaspace/dao/storage_configuration_reader.py")
```

Later on, I call a class of the this module with the same name:

```
config = storage_configuration_reader()
```

If I import it like the above I get the following NameError `NameError: global name 'storage_configuration_reader' is not defined` but if I use the following code:

```
import imp
imp.load_source("storage_configuration_reader","/bi/opt/RNAspace/rnaspace_sources/rnaspace/rnaspace/rnaspace/dao/storage_configuration_reader.py")
import storage_configuration_reader
config = storage_configuration_reader()
```

Then I get this error `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Changing the name of the `imp.load_source` doesn't help to import the object:

```
import imp
imp.load_source("storage_configuration","/bi/opt/RNAspace/rnaspace_sources/rnaspace/rnaspace/rnaspace/dao/storage_configuration_reader.py") 
<module 'storage_configuration' from '/bi/opt/RNAspace/rnaspace_sources/rnaspace/rnaspace/rnaspace/dao/storage_configuration_reader.pyc'>
 import storage_configuration
 config = storage_configuration_reader()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'storage_configuration_reader' is not defined
```

Which is the best way (AKA working way) to import an object like this?

Info: The storage_configuration_reader definition:

```
class storage_configuration_reader(object):
    """ 
    Class configuration_reader: this object read the config file and return the 
    different configuration values
    """
    ...
```

Comment: A module is indeed not callable. Why do you try to call it? Perhaps you wish to call the class within the module instead?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imp.load_source` loads the module using the given `path` and name it using the new `name`, it's not like `from your_module_at_path import your_class_by_name`, it's just like `import your_module_at_path as new_name` (not exactly the same).

Besides, you need to assign the name to a variable to use it:

```
wtf=imp.load_source("new_module_name", your_path)
#wtf is the name you could use directly:
config = wtf.storage_configuration_reader()
```

the name `new_module_name` is stored as a key in dictionary `sys.modules`, you can use it like this:

```
sys.modules['new_module_name'].storage_configuration_reader()
```

**A simpler way** to import a module from some other directory is adding the module's path to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/bi/opt/RNAspace/rnaspace_sources/rnaspace/rnaspace/rnaspace/dao")
import storage_configuration_reader
config = storage_configuration_reader.storage_configuration_reader()
```

Comment: Great answer, very well explained, although it solves this particular problem it doesn't debug my program... Thanks anyway.